# How can I draw a filled in circle with andengine?

Tags: android, geometry, andengine

I am using Andengine GLES 2.0 anchor center branch and I am trying to draw a filled in circle. I tried using the Ellipse class it comes with but all I can get is an outline of a circle not a filled in one like I want. I looked around and all I could find were places showing how to draw an outline so this must be a simple thing. So how can I draw a filled in circle with Andengine GLES 2.0 anchor center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a filled circle/ellipse just go
`mEllipse.setDrawMode(DrawMode.TRIANGLE_FAN);`

Comment: Could you add more code please, to understand this answer?